# RROR Error: Cannot find control with path: formArray

Tags: angular

I have an error with angular ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'notes -> 1' ,'notes -> 0'
this is component.html

```
<div formArrayName="notes">
        <li class="table-row"  *ngFor="let student of etudiantfilter;let note of notes.controls;let i=index"   >
          <div class="col col-1" data-label="student number">{{ i + 1 }}</div>
          <div class="col col-2" data-label="Name"> {{ student.nom }} {{ student.prenom }}</div>
          <div class="col col-3" data-label="note"> <mat-form-field><input matInput  [formControlName]="i">
            <mat-error >
             <span>note 00..20 </span>
    
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
            <label *ngIf="note.invalid" [ngClass] = "'error'"> note is required. </label></div>
    
        </li>
        </div>
```

this is component.ts

```
get notes(): FormArray {
        return this.noteArray.get('notes') as FormArray;
      }
 addNoteField() {
     setTimeout(() => {
     for (let i = 0; i < this.etudiantfilter.length; i++) {
       // @ts-ignore
       this.notes.push(this.fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(note_REGEX)]));
     }
     }, 1000);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a `setTimeout` to fill your `notes` so it is done asynchronously (1 second delay).

In the same time, in your template you iterate on `etudiantfilter` that, I guess, has data in it.

Thus, when you bind on `[formControlName]="i"`, the `nodes[i]` does not yet exist.

Remove this `setTimeout` or add a check in your template so the `ngFor` is done only when `nodes` has some data